# Desktop vanished in 11.04 update

Tags: 11.04, updates

My desktop has completely vanished as has my wall paper.  I think there is some problem with the graphics driver, but natty and unity were working fine before this.  Managed to get a usable computer starting in 2D mode.

As far as I can tell apps work.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. What do you mean by your desktop vanishing?

Comment: It should be fixablke. Let us know what graphics card you have please by opening a terminal and typing lspci and pasting the print out here please

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)